# Scroll Down from a href to div

Tags: jquery, css

i want to scroll down with jQuery from a href to a specific div , my code is :

```
<ul class="menu2">
    <li><a href="#whoweare">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="whoweare"></div>
<div id=services "></div>
```

thank you

Comment: Have you even searched for this? I have seen a load of these all over stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".YourClass").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 500);
});
```