# a href class to scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5-10 links all with the same class/

```
<a class="content-link" href="/profile/about-me/<? echo $row['username'];?>/">
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when the user clicks on this link that then the user is then navigated to the `#profile-body` div using javascript.

Very similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630076/scroll-down-from-a-href-to-div) however the only difference is that instead of having the div which i want the user to be navigated to in the a href like so `<a href="#profile-body">` I need it to be done via javascript so that the link I have in the href actually loads.

Thankyou in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: @Pete take you to the place in the current page and not to worry about the link thats just loaded within the profile body div :)

Comment: @Pete the link loads and the user is taken to the div :)

Comment: @LewisDay That just contradicts your previous comment.

Comment: @Pete the question has already been solved and thats not what im trying to achieve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smooth scroll to div id jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19012495/smooth-scroll-to-div-id-jquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware you're looking for a Javascript solution but just in case you're willing to use Jquery here's a good one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.content-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#profile-body').offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ooops I forgot the event listener, editing my answer.

Comment: thankyou! didn't know that it could be achieved this easily thankyou very much. will mark as answer shortly

Comment: But using e.preventDefault() actually blocks the loading of the new URL.

Comment: @Roberrrt So after the user clicks on the link the page should scroll to the `#profile-body` container and then load a different page? That sounds a little weird. So far I'm not 100% clear on what OP needs. I just provided a solution to scroll to an element.

Comment: What I *think* he needs is: loading the same / new page. And after page load, jump to the hashtag on the page. Applying the hashtag directly in the link would disable the reloading.

Comment: Which is why I was asking questions for clarification, you shouldn't really answer if you don't understand what OP is after

Comment: @Pete I answered when he gave this clarification: *take you to the place in the current page and not to worry about the link thats just loaded within the profile body div*. I don't think I did anything wrong there. If it's not the right answer then OP has the right to not accept my answer. The only reason why I said I'm not 100% clear on what OP needs is because he contradicted his previous comment.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio Wow, you are a fast typer - the comment was made at 14:56:52, you answered at 14:57:05

Comment: @Pete I was writing my answer based on how I understood OP's question. Before hitting submit I scrolled up to see if there were modifications to the question or additional comments. I read his comment which reinforced my understanding so I hit submit. I don't understand why this is still an issue for you.

Answer (score 3):

*This can also be done* with **pure `CSS`.**

```css
body {
  background: #999
}
.mylinks a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2%;
  background: #444;
  color: #999;
}
.mycooldiv {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}
#profile-section1 {
  background: red;
  bottom: 100%
}
#profile-section2 {
  background: blue;
  bottom: 200%
}
#profile-section3 {
  background: green;
  bottom: 300%
}
#profile-section4 {
  background: yellow;
  bottom: 400%
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="mylinks">
    <a class="content-link" href="#profile-section1">section 1 </a>
    <a class="content-link" href="#profile-section2">section 2 </a>
    <a class="content-link" href="#profile-section3">section 3 </a>
    <a class="content-link" href="#profile-section4">section 4 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="mycooldiv" id="profile-section1"></div>
  <div class="mycooldiv" id="profile-section2"></div>
  <div class="mycooldiv" id="profile-section3"></div>
  <div class="mycooldiv" id="profile-section4"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to use jQuery though (unless you're using it already), this is a full vanilla approach. Setting the hash is optional.

Basically, this script is included on the new page, you set the hash manually and then just switch the offsetTop.

```js
(function() {
    window.location.hash = "three";
    document.getElementById('three').offsetTop + "px";
})();
```

```css
div {
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>one</div>
<div id='two'>two</div>
<div id='three'>three</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way of doing so is via JQuery:

```
$(".content-link").click(function () {
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 400);
});
```

With this, you have ALL your .content.link href controlled.

Anyway, it's worth to take a look at [flesler/jquery.scrollTo](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo)